# Replacing dot between defined two tags in all places

Tags: java, regex

I have a XML file and in it there are prices defined for different items as follows..

```
<property>
    <propertyid>AAA</propertyid>
    <price>8.725</price>
    <discount>0</discount>
</property>
<property>
    <propertyid>BBB</propertyid>
    <price>4.135</price>
    <discount>0</discount>
</property>
```

But I want to remove the dot(.) in all of the prices..

eg : new XML string should be as follows..

```
<property>
    <propertyid>AAA</propertyid>
    <price>8725</price>
    <discount>0</discount>
</property>
<property>
    <propertyid>BBB</propertyid>
    <price>4135</price>
    <discount>0</discount>
</property>
```

How can I replace all of this at once using regular expressions in java.

This might be simple question, but I'm new to regular expressions and I need a quick solution.

Thank you all in advance.

BR,

Chamin

Comment: Why does it have to be a regex (as opposed to the obvious tool, an XML parser)? What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: @TimPietzcker a parser would be a good approach, but it will be more complex for this simple task. You have to parse, replace, and write again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = str.replaceAll("<price>(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)</price>", "<price>$1$2</price>");
```

Comment: Thank you Bozho... this is what I was looking for..
I wanted to make sure that dots are removed only within "price" tags..

Answer (score 1):

If you are very sure that file doesn't contain `.` in any other place you could simply use this

```
String content = "...";
String replaced = content.replaceAll("[.]",""); // or simply content.replace(".","");
```

If you are sure `<price>` appears only within `<property` tag you may use this

```
        String content = "<price>87.25</price>";
        String replaced = content.replaceAll(
                 "<price>(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)</price>","<price>$1$2</price>");
        System.out.println(replaced);
```

But the foolproof way is to use xml parsing with Xpath to select only required nodes and then use above `RE` to replace

Comment: Thank you Prashant for your detailed quick response... I was having issue with dot in "price" tag.

So `content.replaceAll( "<price>(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)</price>","<price>$1$2</price>");` is the solution I wanted.

Thank you again.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Boaho's version please find 2 mine. The first does not use regular expression at all since (at list for your example) you do not really need them here. The second uses regular expressions but is not safe for dots that appear outside price tag. Again this works fine for your examples.

```
    String str = "<property>\r\n" + 
            "    <propertyid>AAA</propertyid>\r\n" + 
            "    <price>8.725</price>\r\n" + 
            "    <discount>0</discount>\r\n" + 
            "</property>\r\n" + 
            "<property>\r\n" + 
            "    <propertyid>BBB</propertyid>\r\n" + 
            "    <price>4.135</price>\r\n" + 
            "    <discount>0</discount>\r\n" + 
            "</property>";


    System.out.println(str.replace(".", ""));

    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\.", ""));
```